# Polygons with two different angles

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, polygons

I have the following questions:

Let us consider polygons with only two different interior angles $\alpha$ and $\beta = \pi - \alpha$.

For which frequencies of these angles is it possible to form a closed polygon?

Comment: What is the frequency of an angle?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? It is hard to understand what you are asking for here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the interior angles of a *simple* polygon are $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$, then $\sum(\pi-\alpha_i)=2\pi$. Here we have $k_1$ times $\alpha$ and $k_2$ times $\beta$, so need $k_1(\pi-\alpha)+k_2(\pi-\beta)=2\pi$, or $k_1\pi+(k_2-k_1)\alpha=2\pi$, 
which amounts to either $k_1=k_2=2$ or
$$\alpha=\frac{(k_1-2)\pi}{k_1-k_2}. $$